# Would I be correct in assuming this function runs in linear (O(n)) time?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

Here is a function I wrote in pseudo code:

```js
partition(itemList) {
    numPackets = calculateNumOfPackets(listSize, packetSize); 
    indexOfNextItem = 0; 
    packetQueue = initialize(numPackets); 
    for (i = 0; < numPackets; i++) {
        // Initialized as a fixed-size list 
        Packet p = createNew(packetSize); 
        for (j = indexOfNextItem; j < itemList.length; j++) {
           // hasRoom() returns false when packet is at capacity
            if (p.hasRoom()) 
                // Guaranteed to run in constant time due to predefined capacity
                p.add(item[j]); 
            else {
                indexOfNextItem = j; // keep track of next index for inner loop
                break; 
            }   
        } // end inner
        packetQueue.add(p); 
    } // end outer
    return packetQueue; 
}
```

As I hope is clear, this just does partitioning and returns a partitioned queue of "packets" that contains the items of the input list. Now I'm pretty sure this is running in linear time because the inner loop isn't running fully for each iteration of the outer loop; it's only running until the current packet is full, at which point it keeps a cache of the index where it left off and then breaks out of the inner loop. As a result I suspect this is actually running in linear time.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I see no `n` in the code. Do you mean to write `O(numPackets)`? `O(itemList)`? Please clarify expected complexity in relation to which input(s).

Comment: Please give us the time complexity of all the methods being called inside partition() or https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Added more comments to explain how each method is implemented.

Comment: @tucuxi This is kind of part of the question. I honestly have no idea how I should look at it.

Comment: What are `listSize`, `packetSize`? Are they some attributes of `itemList`? What is `p.hasRoom`, what is `createNew`? Where is `packetQueue` initialised?

Comment: @trincot listSize is just an integer representing the number of items in the input list. packetSize is the same since a packet is implemented internally as a list with a fixed capacity. packetQueue is initialized in the same function. I added it for clarity.

Comment: `p.add(item[j])` should be `p.add(itemList[j])`, correct?

Comment: Didn't you missed an asignement of `nextOfNextItem` in the case where the loop ends without breaking? The algorithm seems suspiciously wrong to me but I am not sure of what it does in the first place and a "*partitioning and returns a partitioned queue of "packets"*" is not very clear either.

Comment: Shouldn't `packetQueue = initialize(capacity);` be `packetQueue = initialize(numPackets);`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Given a list of items, the algorithm is supposed to add a certain number of these items to packets (represented as fixed-size lists) and returns a queue of said packets. So if the input list had 100 items, and the max packet capacity allowed is 10, then you'd get a queue of 10 packets each having 10 items. (It's also very possible to be wrong since it's not tested.)

Comment: @FieryPhoenix, where you have `capacity`, you mean `packetSize`, correct? Such that `listSize <= packetSize*numPackets`?

Comment: correct! Sorry this is just psuedo code since it's a bit messy. I haven't implemented any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `createNew(packetSize)` is linear in `packetSize`, `initialize(numPackets)` is linear in `numPackets` and all of `p.hasRoom()`,  `p.add()`, `itemList[i]` and `packetQueue.add(p)` are O(1), your algorithm is O(`listSize`) (assuming `listSize` is `len(itemList)`.

The sketch of the proof is that each inner loop will execute at most `packetSize` O(1) operations, and that inner loop will be executed at most `ceil(listSize / packetSize)`, thus the total number of operations will run at most `(numPackets + 1) * packetSize * n`, where `n` is a constant related to the number of operations done in each loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, this is what I'd figured. Apologies for the messy pseudocode again :)

Answer (score 1):

One of your comments states that:

> Given a list of items, the algorithm is supposed to add a certain
> number of these items to packets (represented as fixed-size lists) and
> returns a queue of said packets. So if the input list had 100 items,
> and the max packet capacity allowed is 10, then you'd get a queue of
> 10 packets each having 10 items.

If this is true, then, since each item is only included in 1 packet, your algorithm is linear in the number of items (`O(itemList.length)`) - assuming that placing items into packets is constant-time.

Counting nested loops only makes  sense if the loop counters are independent. If you know that, as in this case, every item in a list is being visited once and only once, and that visit is constant-time, you can confidently state that such code is linear in the number of items.